# Is it possible to call a Oracle Function with jpa @Query

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to call an Oracle function from a jpa hibernate `@Query`?

This works for me:

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ResultDTO(g,l.country,r.name) "
            + "FROM Items g, Service l, Service r, Service s"
            +" WHERE s.id = g.id" 
            +" AND s.location = l.name"
            +" AND s.serviceType = 'type'"
            +" AND l.serviceType = 'Location'"
            +" AND l.area = r.name" 
            +" AND r.serviceType = 'Region'")
    public ResultDTO[] name();
```

But I want to call in the constructor of `ResultDTO` a Oracle Function with two parameters. Like I would do it with native SQL.

added in query: `get_trans_lac(l.country, 'en')`

```
@Query("SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ResultDTO(g, get_translation(l.country, 'en'),r.name) "
            + "FROM Items g, Service l, Service r, Service s"
            +" WHERE s.id = g.id" 
            +" AND s.location = l.name"
            +" AND s.serviceType = 'type'"
            +" AND l.serviceType = 'Location'"
            +" AND l.area = r.name" 
            +" AND r.serviceType = 'Region'")
    public ResultDTO[] name();
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

I get a Nullpointer by start of the application.

this: 
    `SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ResultDTO(g, FUNCTION(get_translation, l.country, 'en'),r.name)` gives also a Nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself, but there seems to be a thing called `FUNCTION(functionName, parameters, ...)` in JPQL (JPA 2.1 and later, `FUNC` in JPA previous to 2.1), which will call a native function.

So the first line in your query would be:

```
SELECT NEW com.test.project.dto.ResultDTO(g, FUNCTION('get_translation', l.country, 'en'),r.name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but got same result: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method...` and `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`. Any other solution?

Comment: It looks like `FUNCTION` could be an EclipseLink only thing. Sorry. When using the criteria API there's a method defined in the `CriteriaBuilder` interface, [`function`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...-), which inserts a call to a database function. Since that exists in the interface definition one would think the same functionality should be available in JPQL.